# Show that P(A|B) = 1 does not imply B is a subset of A if we omit the hypothesis that for all x in S, P(x) is not equal to zero.

Tags: probability

Let A and B be events in a sample space (S,P) with P(B) not equal to zero. Suppose also that for all x in S, P(x) is not equal to zero.

In part (a) I proved that P(A|B) = 1 iff B is a subset of A.

I don't understand how to proof what is stated in the Title.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider you can write $P(B) = P(B_1\cup B_2) = P(B_1)+P(B_2)$ with some disjunct $B_1, B_2$ and $P(B_2)=0$

Comment: If B is in the sample space S,having $P(B_2)=0$ does not necessarily imply that $B_2$ is an empty set, right?? I guess taking  $P(B_2)=0$ is valid because we omit the hypothesis and even though B is in the sample space it does not mean every subset of B should have a nonzero probability right?

Comment: Yes, this is just a hint how you can construct a counter example. You shoul choose $B=B_1\cup B_2$ with $P(B_1)\gt 0$ and some $B_2$ with $P(B_2)=0$ but $B_2\neq\emptyset$. Don't think to much about it .. you can even construct such an counter example on $S=\{0,1\}$ or sth like that